# How are assembly variables implemented?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm a little confused about how variables are implemented in Assembly. I know that the following declaration creates a named memory location in the program's `data` section:

```
.section .data
        var:
                .long 23
```

Then you can access the variable such as:

```
movl var, %eax //read from var location
```

What I'm not clear on is how the above instructions are actually implemented. I was under the impression that a memory reference, even an absolute memory reference, needed to be loaded into a register before it could be used.

Does the assembler need to convert the above instruction into multiple instructions, such as:

```
leal var, %ebx
movl (%ebx), %eax
```

Or does the assembler keep track of the address of `var` and access that location as though it were an absolute immediate access, e.g.:

```
movl ($addr_of_var), %eax
```

Comment: No.  You have a misunderstanding of the requirements.  You do not have to load the address into a register.  Look at the instruction reference for the `MOV` family of instructions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The x86 instruction set does not require memory addresses to be loaded into registers before they can be used -- pretty much all instructions can use direct or indirect memory references in the instruction.  See the [Intel architecture manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for more details.

The requirement to load addresses into registers first is a characterisic of some RISC cpus, like MIPS.

Comment: Thanks! Is the second statement above accurate? (Does the assembler keep track of absolute references for variables?)

Comment: @David: The assmebler generally deals with symbol references symbolically, leaving it up to the linker to determine the final locations of everything, and fix up the code as needed.